# Uploading string value into azure storage location as a file content

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a string value as file content into azure storage location but without writing any code and using azure components only. Is there any option available?

Comment: How's going? Do you have any more questions ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this：

1. Write a string into .txt file and [upload the file to a storage container on Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal#upload-a-block-blob).
2. Generate a long lifetime SAS token on Azure Portal:
   [image]

and use [blob rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) to upload it to a blob, you can do it directly in postman:

[image]

Result:
[image]

3. Use [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-action) to do this. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Let me know if you have any more questions.